# $\mathbf{RP}^m \times \mathbf{RP}^n$ bounds a $(m+n+1)$-d manifold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, cobordism

How to show whether $\mathbf{RP}^m \times \mathbf{RP}^n$ bounds a $(m+n+1)$-d manifold or not?

For example, could we prove or disprove $\mathbf{RP}^2 \times \mathbf{RP}^2$ bounds a 5d manifold?

Comment: That helps! how about others

Comment: @NoelLundström That isn't true. One can do surgery to make any orientable manifold non-orientable, and surgery does not effect cobordism type. For example, one can do surgery on a sphere to obtain a Klein bottle which witnesses the fact that the Klein bottle is a boundary.

Comment: Thanks – Connor Malin - it helps! how about in general

Comment: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Unoriented_bordism

Comment: @ConnorMalin Right, I realized my mistake right after posting hahah. That's the curse of the commenter.

Comment: To add to Connor's link above, $\mathbb{R}P^\text{odd}$ are boundaries, so $\mathbb{R}P^m \times \mathbb{R}P^n$ is not a boundary iff $m$ and $n$ are even.